# plaid lifetime of access_token, _item and _user

Tags: plaid

I am trying to understand the lifetime of a plaid **access_token** (returned by /connect and used to /connect/get) as well as the plaid **_user** and **_item** fields of an account. The **_user** field is undocumented, and the **_item** field according to the documentation is

> "An id unique to the accounts of a particular access token."
>   (https://www.plaid.com/docs/#connect)

My guess from the setup is that:

- An **_item** is used to universally identify a set of accounts with the same login (e.g. wells fargo debit and credit accounts linked together) regardless of the client accessing the accounts' data. An **_item**'s lifetime never ends.
- An **access_token** is generated by plaid for a (client_id, _item) pair and grants the client_id access to accounts associated with _item. If the user owning the accounts changes his login information, or if plaid revokes access to the client_id, the access_token becomes useless and a new one needs to be generated in the same way.
- A **_user** universally identifies a person who may own multiple sets of accounts each identified by an _item. I am unsure as to what guarantees plaid gives with regards to the accuracy of this field (in other words, does plaid guarantee that two _user's are equal if and only if the respective persons they refer to are the same?)

How correct is my understanding?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plaid **access_tokens** are valid indefinitely or until a user is removed from Plaid using a DELETE request. If the underlying user's login information is changed, the existing **access_token** will actually remain valid however require a [PATCH](https://plaid.com/docs/#update-user) request to update the user's login information accordingly.

You are correct that the **_item** is the highest level identifier for multiple accounts that are all attached to the same set of credentials at a given financial institution. As such, the **_item** unique to a single **access_token**.

**_user** is a deprecated field that is no longer returned by the API.

Comment: I see access_tokens going invalid after some good number of days in the sandbox environment. I assume it only happens in Sandbox. Is it so? @Carl